# Link entity causing exception, not sure why?

Tags: xml, fetchxml, adxstudio-portals, adx

I have the below FetchXML link-entity, to execute on a Dynamics portal. However i'm getting the liquid error `Liquid error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`. any ideas why? How do I go about fixing this?

I believe its this link-entity it complains about.

```
<link-entity name="product" from="productid" to="TEST_course" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="productAlias">
<attribute name="TEST_faculty" />
<attribute name="name" />
<link-entity name="TEST_faculty" from="TEST_facultyid" to="TEST_faculty" link-type="inner" alias="ae">
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="TEST_routecases" operator="eq" value="4" />
</filter>
</link-entity>
</link-entity>
```